GoogleMaps places autocomplete dark mode results?
I'm using GoogleMaps JS with places lib to autocomplete a city. But I always get the results in light mode despite the browser and system being in dark mode. Is there a way to force dark mode for the results, maybe in the options? Didn't find anything in the docs.
 var options = {
     types: ['(regions)'],
     componentRestrictions: {country: ["us", "ca"]}
 };
 var input = document.getElementById('city');
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);            



So I found a CSS work-around, posting in case it helps someone but CSS based rules can be broken so it's not a full proof solution. Hoping someone has a better solution than that.
.pac-container {
    background-color: #282828 !important;
    color: #EEE !important;
}
.pac-item{
    color: #AAA !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #333 !important;
}
.pac-item-query {
    color: #EEE !important;
}


Too bad the question was closed in favor of a thread where the response is ever worse than this work around.
